# Syntax error in embedded for loop in Lambda function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm sure this is a simple fix but I am getting a syntax error on line11 which is the embedded for loop (for j in range) in the following lambda function.

```
import math
import random

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    shots = int(event['pi_shots'])
    rate = int(event['report_rate'])
    pi_values=[]
    incircle_sum = 0
    for i in range(0, rate):
        incircle = 0
        for j in range(0,shots/rate):
            random1 = random.uniform(-1.0,1.0)
            random2 = random.uniform(-1.0,1.0)
            if( ( random1*random1 + random2*random2 ) < 1 ):
                incircle += 1
        incircle_sum += incircle
        pi = 4*(float(incircle_sum)/((shots/rate)*(i+1)))
        pi_values.append(pi)
    return pi_values
```

Comment: Please post the exact error.

Comment: This code works for me once I indent every line below 'def' as it should be. Also, FYI, this isn't a lambda function (aka anonymous function) because it has a name.

Comment: Can you please add the erorr you're getting? (and indent the code)

Comment: Please don't delete your question once you've found an answer. If you solve the problem on your own, post an answer to this question so people in the future can benefit.

Comment: @TubesHerder this is an AWS Lambda function. Unfortunate naming I know. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the error is coming from the stop value of `range(start, stop)`. The argument for [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) should be integer. Therefore convert the division result to `int` as

```
for j in range(0, int(shots/rate)):
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue however I'm getting another error of an unexpected indentation on line 13 two lines down, is there an issue with the loop itself?

Comment: @JamesMills : It doesn't look like so to me. Make sure you have correct tab indentation. Don't mix spaces and tabs.

Comment: Instead of `int(shots / rate)` you could also use `shots // rate` (see [PEP 238](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) for details).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `range` built-in, wrong. The second parameter of the `range` built-in must be an `integer`.
You have to type cast `shots/rate` to `integer`. Try this one instead:

```py
import math
import random


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    shots = int(event['pi_shots'])
    rate = int(event['report_rate'])
    pi_values = []
    incircle_sum = 0
    for i in range(0, rate):
        incircle = 0
        for j in range(0, int(shots / rate)):
            random1 = random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
            random2 = random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0)
            if ((random1 * random1 + random2 * random2) < 1):
                incircle += 1
        incircle_sum += incircle
        pi = 4 * (float(incircle_sum) / ((shots / rate) * (i + 1)))
        pi_values.append(pi)
    return pi_values
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue however I'm getting another error of an unexpected indentation on line 13 two lines down, is there an issue with the loop itself?

Comment: @JamesMills You have to indent `four spaces` (or using `tab` key) after each `def` or `for` or `if` till the end of it. However, the code is indented fine, copy-paste mine instead of yours.

Comment: The fact that this is happening suggests that the poster is using Python 3, not Python 2.7 as the tag indicates. Either that, or there's a \_\_future\_\_ import that's missing from the code snippet.